# strange behaviour of grep in UNIX

Tags: unix, grep

When I type the command

```
$ grep \\\\h junk
```

then the shell should interpret `\\\\h` as `\\h` - as the two pairs of `\\` each 
become `\` .  `grep` in turn, should interpret `\\h` as `\h` as `\\` becomes `\`, so `grep` should search for the pattern `\h` in `junk`, which it is doing successfully.

But it's not working for `\\\\$`. Why?

Comment: better on superuser.com

Comment: Isn't `$` some special symbol too? Try `\\\$`

Comment: @Draco Ater Unfortunately that's not enough, don't forget that the shell gets first bat against backslashed chars... which turns \\$ into \$, which grep then interprets as the EOL symbol.

Comment: @Happy: ok, i believe i see the difference. in this question and the other.  reopening.  please double-check that my edits are what you intended to say -- i've used markdown formatting for codeblocks (4-space-indent) and string literals (backticks), so that avoids having to type `\\\\\\\\h` just to see `\\\\h`.  hope i got the numbers right.

Comment: Try using `echo` to see what input is going into `grep`.  I.E., `echo \\\$` will give output as `\$`.

Answer (score 6):

To return lines with a dollar sign, another way without escapes is:

```
grep "[$]" file
```

To find lines with the literal `\$`:

```
grep "[\][$]" file
```

Comment: Very nice!  Testing in bash, you don't need quotes either!

Answer (score 2):

Returns only lines with the dollar sign in it.

```
grep "\\$" application/bootstrap.php
```

Because $ is a regex command as well ( end of line ), you have to quote it to get the double slashes past your shell and into grep.

Answer (score 1):

Grep always uses \ to quote the next character, so \h simply becomes h in your example, since \h is not "special":

```
$ cat file
\a
a

$ grep \\a file
\a
a

$ grep \\\\a file
\a
```

Comment: As in your last example, grep \\\\a searches for \a, shouldn't
\\\\$ be searched for \$ because shell passes grep as \\$ and grep
converts it to \$.
am I correct?

Comment: As others have pointed out, $ matches the end of the string, so you have to quote it. If you want to search for the two characters '\$', then grep needs `\\\$`, and quoting for the shell gives you `\\\\\\$`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to match the character '$', the pattern:

> [$]

is the easiest way to specify it without getting tangled up in multiple levels of character-escapes.  Or if you're trying to match the two characters: '\$', then

> [\\][$]

will do it.

Answer (score 1):

\h is not a special escape for grep, so '\h' should find a \h in a file, which it does.
The shell removes the first \ before grep sees it, as \ is special (type `ls \\` and it says ls: : So such file or directory ). So to match "\h" in a file, use grep \h, or '\h' to avoid the first \ --> \ reduction by the shell.

Now \$ : \ is reduced to \ by the shell, and grep sees \$ and because $ is special in regexes (like +,.,* etc), \$ is a literal dollar sign, as a simple test file will show you. See the man page for re_format (7). So this matches all lines with a dollar sign.

So if you want to match a literal "\$" in a file, we need to think: \$ is unescaped by the shell to literal $, and \ to : try `ls \\\$' and you get "ls: \$: No such file or directory". So in`grep \\$ file`, grep sees \$ and interprets that as $ again... So we want grep to see \\\$ (which it will unescape again to \$), so we can put single quotes around that and avoid headaches, or escape all the special characters for the shell too:`grep \\\\$ file`. This works.

That's why I almost always put single quotes around the first grep argument, so I only have to think about what grep will do, and not about the shell as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is interpreting `\\` as `\`, and `$` as a first character of some control sequences, like variable names. Therefore `\\\\` is interpreted by your shell as literal `\\` (as you think), but `$` needs to be escaped to be interpreted as literal character. Use `\\\\\\\$` (seven backslashes) or `'\\\$'` (text in apostrophes is interpreted literally by shell).

Comment: sorry I mistakenly typed wrong question. Now I have edited it.
Please explain answer.

Comment: But it's neither working with \\\\\$(five backslashes), nor with
'\\$'

Comment: Please explain "not working" with a reproducible case. i.e. what contains the file you are "grepping", what command you run, what result you got you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just `grep '\\$'`? Single quotes prevent almost all interpolation.